# Samba server synchronisation

Tags: server, samba

I configured samba / file server with Ubuntu 14.04 which is working fine.
I would like to create a “backup or failover” system in case this one stops working (e.g. power cut).

This samba has the IP 192.168.1.10 and has 2 hard drives, small one for Ubuntu and huge one for the data and files.

Is it possible to configure another one (say 192.168.1.11 and also with 2 hard drives), so that any updates or changes in the data hard drive (second hard drive) of the first one will be also copied into the data hard drive of the second one automatically and immediately (synchronisation from the first to the second and not the other way round as the first will be the main/ primary server)?

Many thanks

Madona33

Comment: You might wish to consider rsync: http://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/answers/Networking/Using_rsync_to_mirror_data_between_servers or http://drbd.linbit.com/

Answer (score 0):

I am currently doing this on a fairly old box using Ubuntu server and [BitTorrent Sync](http://www.getsync.com/). It was my first Ubuntu Server installation which was much easier than I expected.  BitTorrent Sync was a snap to set up, can be easily administered remotely on both instances, syncs almost instantly with no intervention.  I don't think the backup server even has Samba installed.